# Creating a graph where different nodes have the same label?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Lets take a basic graph in `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node("A")
G.add_node("B")
G.add_edge("A","B")
```

Exporting that as `gml` yields:

```
graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "A"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "B"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
  ]
]
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to have two different nodes with the same name such that my gml file looks like this:

```
graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "A"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "A"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
  ]
]
```

At least in the file the id numbers are different and therefore the nodes uniquely identified even with having the same name. This file can be opened with yEd without any issues.

Judging from the syntax I presume this isn't possible in `networkx`, so what other ways are there to do this?

Background:

I have a directed graph where two nodes `X` and `Y` both have the same successor `Z` but I want `X` and `Y` to each have their own `Z` instead of both pointing to the same `Z`. Basically I want a directed tree where each node has only one predecessor while duplicates in the tree are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  You need to define your own function which will take a node as input and output its label as a string.  This is a bit of a hack since the function is really intended to create the string which serves as the label in the case that the node doesn't have a label that is automatically converted into a string.  But it works.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('a', 'b')
G.add_edge('b','c')

def stringizer(x):  #replaces both 'a' and 'b' with 'a'
   if x == 'a':
       return 'a'
   elif x == 'b':
       return 'a'
   else:
       return x

nx.write_gml(G, path='tmp.gml', stringizer=stringizer)
```

The output gives both node 'a' and 'b' the label 'a'.

```
graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "a"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "a"
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "c"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
  ]
  edge [
    source 1
    target 2
  ]
]
```

One way to do this in practice would be to create a dictionary `D[node]` which gives the label and then define

```
def stringizer(node):
    return D[node]
```

Comment: I didn't know `stringizer` yet, that's very helpful.